# jQuery UI - Allow sortable elements to be positioned freely on the screen

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable

I am trying to use jQuery UI's [Draggable](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/) & [Sortable](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/) to make an object able to be freely moved within an element, without having to remain next to another object.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I tried for a while to use jQuery UI for some quite specific tasks, and noticed that the tweaks/'hacks' I was using to customize jQuery UI to my needs were more cumbersome than writing my own functions from scratch. Just something to keep in mind.

Comment: Do you have an idea on how you wish to get the 'order' from the list? The whole idea of the sortable plugin is that it's well, sortable. If you provide use with a bit more information on what kind of interaction you expect it's easier to help

Comment: It is currently set up to serialize the data from the list, but I guess I could also set it up as an array. Everything works well but this; I want the customization option for people to move items along the x-axis within the container div. Once finished, I want the sortable to serialize or build an array of the data.

Answer (score 0):

If I got the question you were trying to ask properly. This is generally achieved from just using the draggable option only.

See this [demo here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/).